# problems with iFrame and Safari (on Mac)

Tags: html, iframe, safari

I am using this piece of code(I am posting it below) to display PDFs in my website and it was working perfectly until 2 month ago when it became impossible for Safari users(only those who uses Mac) to display PDFs(they get a white page).
With safari on windows it works normally. Two users that have safari on mac have reported a blank space instead of the pdf.

I tried some solutions I found on the web but they didn't work, I am really stuck, is there anyone who can help me please?

Thanks so much!

The code is:

```
<iframe src='http://docs.google.com/gview?url=www.foo.ch/doc/320140522145451.pdf&embedded=true' style='width:980px; height:700px;' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the target doc is still exists or not?

Comment: sadly it still exists. people with other systems than mac/safari can browse the pdf and download it.